# How to set log4j2.xml Configuration status

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, log4js-node

Can someone help me to set ***Configuration*** ***status*** from properties file.

Here i have tried as below in log4j2.xml and its writing in server log as *ERROR Invalid status level specified*

Configuration status="${bundle:Logger-application:status.level}"....

and i have a ***Logger-application.properties*** with the field ***status.level=debug***

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You might take a look at [configuration with properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#Properties),[status messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#StatusMessages) and [configuration syntax](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html#ConfigurationSyntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here configured Configuration status properly through `logger-application.properties` but make sure log4j XML pointing to which properties file, if you have a duplicate copy of `logger-application.properties` inside configuration folder then it treats that as a priority, check your configuration and component level application properties.